# How can I access the artefact from a pull request for which a build was run?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using azure for a windows app and so I don't really need to go as far as CD as that isn't really relevant.  We eventually plan to move to the cloud but for now that is not the case.

I have now got my .net (c#) build running as a build pipeline and I have a develop branch which Pull Requests are used to merge in changes.  What I want is for a tester to be able to pick up the build artefact that was created for a particular bug or product backlog item when the pull request was successfully completed.  Is this possible without having a Release Pipeline?  I don't currently have a subscription that would allow me to create a release pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I access the artefact from a pull request for which a build was run?

Indeed, just as Lucas said, if we are starting from the pull request to solve this problem, it is really difficult. But we could try reverse thinking to start with the build pipeline.

Azure devops provided us some [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), like `Build.BuildId`, `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId`.

So, we could use the REST API [Pull Requests - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) in the build pipeline to update the comment with the link to the artifact.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.1
```

Since the current build is triggered by a pull request, we could use the predefined variable `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` to get the `pullRequestId` directly.

Now, we just need to get the link of the artifact, we could use the [Artifacts - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) to get the artifact info:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=4.1
```

We could get the `buildId` by the predefined variable `Build.BuildId`, then we will get the download URL:

[image]

So the idea of summing up my solution is to use REST API Pull Requests - Update in the build pipeline to update the comment of the pull request, which contains the download path of the artifact.

Note: You could also add custom conditions in the REST API task in the build pipeline:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

So, with this setting, only the build triggered by the pull request will execute this rest api task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer it is clear to me that what I am trying to do is not what was intended...

Comment: @TimRutter, Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: The information was useful in that its made me realise that its not worth persuing any further.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The pull request build that you defined can publish artifacts, see [this documentation to see how to do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Once those artifacts are published, your tested can browse/download them on the build run page (click on header pa> "Related" > click on "#number of artifacts you publish# published").

Alternatively, you could add a task to [copy your artifacts to an Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops), but that would require more configuration.

Comment: thanks for that. I guess what I'm really asking for is a link in the product backlog item to the artifact.  You have a link to the pull request but its not immediately obvious how to get from that to the correct artifact

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't think such a feature exist out of the box; you would have to create a bot that post a comment on the PR with the artifact link... That would be a good amount of work.

Comment: ok thanks, that sounds like too much effort at this stage!  so is a typical process for this to trigger a release build that could then be used for testing?

Answer (score 0):

One can find build id with branchName filter :

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0&reasonFilter=pullRequest&definitions={buildDefinitionId}&branchName=refs/pull/{pullRequestId}/merge
```

Once builder id has been retrieved, get artifact by name :

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=6.0
```